# Javascript - Load new cache on deploy

Tags: javascript, php, css, caching

I want to load a new version of my javascript,css,html etc.. every time i deploy my page. I saw that i could add `?<version>` to the script's src link, Is there any other new/more reliable way of doing this?

**UPDATE** I'm looking for something like a variable that would allow me to update the URL automatically if a new file is loaded rather than me renaming the files manually. Is this possible?

Comment: here are some techniques https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that an elegant way is to use a gulpfile which rename your *.css and *.js filename to include a hash of file content at the end.

**1) Gulp library : deal with filename** 

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev
Example of what it does : transform filename unicorn.css into unicorn-d41d8cd98f.css

**2) Gulp library : deal with index.html include**

To inject css and js, you could use another gulp librairie :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject
This one allow you to include automatically css and js in your index.html using file directories.

**3) What you have to do**

All you have to do is to create a gulp task which use these two library. I swear it's not to hard. I don't have enough time to do a demonstration (I'll do it in the next few days).

This solution presents two advantage :

- Only changed files are cache reloaded on the user side
- You don't need to use an external js library inside your project,
  which increase a risk of failure.

Comment: Yes, sory i forgot to mention it is a big project so im looking for something that would allow me to update the URL automatically rather than me renaming the files manully

Comment: Nicely explained I think this will be my choice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the resource's last-edited time to the src/href of the resource's element, or add an MD5 of all related times if you're linking to an aggregation script that might include sub-directories, etc.

http://verens.com/2008/04/09/javascript-cache-problem-solved/

Comment: Thanks, so if i would use MD5 then if the file was changed it would be updated dynamically or i would have to specificy different versions of the script every time i would change the code?

Comment: The link I added shows what to do. Basically, the link to the resource is dynamically generated by having the server check the date/time of the resource.